# URL in Java : Why does the String part after "+" not be considered?

Tags: java, url, inputstream

I'm working with `URL's` and more precisely on Stack Overflow.

The structure of the `questions` part of the site's `URLs` is :

```
/questions/tagged/tag+anotherTag+lastTag
```

When trying to work with the `URL`, I just get the questions for the first Tag.

### Example

```
URL url = null;
InputStream is = null;
BufferedReader br;
String line;

try{
    url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cobol+hibernate");
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("<div class=\"tags")){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(url);
```

### Output

```
<div class="tags t-cobol">
<div class="tags t-batch-file t-cobol t-mainframe t-vsam">
<div class="tags t-cobol t-mainframe">
<div class="tags t-cobol t-opencobol t-microfocus">
<div class="tags t-cobol">
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cobol+hibernate
```

### Expected Output

```
// Nothing because there is no question under both tags
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cobol+hibernate
```

Actual Link is an [empty page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cobol+hibernate) (in the way that never any question has been posted with both tags together) and as you can see, the code just looks for questions identified with the first tag.

---

`Cobol+Hibernate` is just an example that explains the problem very well, I know there is no logic to put these two tags together.

Comment: "Actual Link is an empty page and as you can see, the code just looks for questions identified with the first tag." Funny, the "empty page" appears to search for questions with both tags for me.

Comment: @Powerlord Empty in the way that it does not contain any question containing both tags...

Comment: It's because the plus is acting as an AND operator.  It's searching for items that include both tags.  Try with tags like java+swing and it works just fine.  It gets you an empty page because no one has asked a question with both cobol and hibernate as tags.

Comment: That page is encoded in UTF-8.  Your use of `new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())` will read the page's bytes using your own machine's default charset.   Is your default charset UTF-8?  (If you're running on Windows, the answer is no.)

Comment: @ChaseHenslee Which is somewhat non-intuitive since searching for non-tags is done via a query string.  + is used to replace space in query strings.

Comment: Guys, I suggest you look at the only answer or read the question again.

Comment: Maybe in the future don't use a case where even if it worked correctly you'd get the same result.  Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: @ChaseHenslee this is just the contrary. I'll edit my question, sorry for the tone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `curl` command and output sheds some light:

```
$ curl 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cobol+hibernate'
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/questions/tagged/cobol">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

That is, the request is redirected, dropping the second tag.

Also an extract from the output of `curl -v ...`:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Location: /questions/tagged/cobol
```

It would appear that you need some rep to be able to search for multiple tags at the same time. If I open `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cobol+hibernate` in an incognito window (where I'm not logged in), the 2nd and further tags are dropped.

So if you want to do this query in Java,
it would appear that you need to login programmatically.

I guess this is because searching for multiple tags can be a burden on the database, and so its use is restricted to experienced users.
You can probably get a definitive answer on MSE.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Tried it in incognito and you're totally right. Thank you for the time. Do you have any link to know how to login programitaclly?

Comment: It's been a while since I played with it, but the Stack Exchange API should help with that: https://api.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you very much. Will def. check it out. Here, have an accept.